# What does the 17th-century German phrase »den kopff herunter hawen« mean?

Tags: phrase

The below paragraph comes from *The Süddeutsche Zeitung* article “[Reiß die Himmel auf](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/welt-reiss-die-himmel-auf-1.3308177)”. What does the phrase *den kopff herunter hawen* mean (highlighted in bold)? And what's the modern equivalent of *hawen*? Is it *haben*?

> Es gibt Zeiten der Verzweiflung. In einer solchen Zeit schrieb der Jesuit Friedrich Spee das Lied "O Heiland reiß die Himmel auf". Das war vor bald 400 Jahren, im Dreißigjährigen Krieg, es war die Zeit der Hexenverfolgung; Spee war ihr leidenschaftlicher Gegner - und er war der Beichtvater ihrer Opfer. Er hat die Folter gesehen, den Hass des Mobs und den Wahn in den Augen der Richter. Er hat die Opfer in Blut und Ekel liegen sehen. Er hat die Urteile gehört, Urteile "Im Namen des Vaters und des Sohnes und des Heiligen Geistes". Er wusste um die Unschuld der Opfer, aber er hat kein Urteil verhindern, er hat nur trösten können. Er hat sich überlegt, ob er sich selbst "**den kopff herunter hawen**" lässt. Aber dann hat er ihn lieber zum Denken benutzt, hat weitergetröstet und weiterbegleitet zum Scheiterhaufen - und Gott angeschrien in seinem Lied: Reiß auf! Reiß ab! Schlag aus!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly guess that it means *den Kopf herunterhauen,* i.e., Spee is considering to have himself beheaded.

I presume that the difficult part is to identify *hawen* with *hauen,* so I restrict myself to give arguments for this:

- [The Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hauen) states that *hauen* was *houwen* in Middle High German. [Grimm’s dictionary](//www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/hauen) reports forms with *w* up to the 17<sup>th</sup> century. Also consider the English cognate *to hew.*
- The latter *w* originated from *uu,* where *u* can correspond to the modern *v* or *u,* since they were only beginning to separate letters at that time. (Also remember the English *double-u).* Substituting this, *hawen* becomes *hauven,* which easier to identify with *hauen.*
- The pronunciation *[haʊ̯ʷən]* or even *[haʊ̯wən]* is very close to the actual pronunciation [haʊ̯ən]. *[w]* denotes the sound at the beginning of the English *where* and can be described as a consonant *u* sound.

Comment: Ich bin der gleichen Meinung, möchte nur fragen ob der Ausdruck nicht dieselbe Bedeutung hätte, wenn "hawen" hier für "haben" stände?

Comment: @Beta: Ich denke nicht. »sich den Kopf herunter haben« ergibt im heutigen Deutsch keinen Sinn. Wenn, dann würde ich *haben* wie im Englischen lesen, also ähnlich zu *lassen.* Aber der Artikel gibt hier bereits ein *lassen* vor, wenn auch außerhalb des Zitats. Wenn hier nicht falsch zitiert wurde, hätten wir also zwei Wörter, die dasselbe bedeuten.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a bit speculative. From the context of the article, the described poet felt desperation along with the victims of the witch hunt - possibly to the point of suicidality. I would thus suggest that "hawen" should be transcribed as "hauen".